# How can I check if a PictureBox's image has been modified?

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox

I'm working on a super top-secret application right now that has a PictureBox on it.  There are some options to edit the image inside of the PictureBox, including (but not limited to) sepia, grayscale, and some rotations.

At the moment, however, there isn't any way to check if the image has been modified - as I've been trying to create a "Would you like you save your changes??!" dialog box, which would appear if the image has been modified in any way.

I've got all of the actual *modifications* set in stone at the moment - all I need is a reliable method of checking if the PictureBox's image has been modified.

Comment: Strange question, how can you *not* know that the code *you* wrote has modified the image?

Answer (score 2):

mmm.. Every time the user use an option to edit the image, just set a flag to true. That way you know that the image has change.. in fact, you are changing it somehow, so you know when is modified!

Answer (score 0):

Does the BackgroundImageChanged Event fire? Use that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagechanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> There are some options to edit the image inside of the PictureBox,
>   including (but not limited to) sepia, grayscale, and some rotations.

```
private bool isChanged = false;

void Apply_sepia() {
   isChanged = true;
   // apply sepia
}


void close(...) {
    if(isChanged) {
        if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", SomethingOptions.YesNo) == MessageBoxOptions.Yes) {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    } else {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

I obviously cannot remember what the correct property names are.. however you get the gist.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot...thank you! I was assuming there was a "Modified" property, like with richTextBox! :0